# I am recently getting crash in FrameLayout.java line 525 android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren

Tags: android, crash

Please check the stack trace anyone has an idea?
It seems the crash is from different android OS versions so may me it id, not OS related issue.

```
 Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:525)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15604)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2105)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1855)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1079)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5839)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:835)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:634)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:600)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:821)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5318)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:717)
```

Comment: Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference,  NullPoint errors typically occur because you are trying to attach to VIEW that isn't part of the loaded layout.

Comment: Yes, you are right thanks buddy.